# How to get landing page after successful transaction

Tags: landing-pages

Could you please guide me how do I get a landing page after successful transaction - landing page which says "your order has been placed successfully"

Answer (score 0):

On Magento, the customer would see this anyway.

[image: Magento Thank You Page]

Comment: I am not sure why my developer is not able to get me the landing page.